# $push replacing values in array instead of adding

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I am a begginer using nodeJs, mongoose and MongoDB and i ran into a problem that after several hours of research i cannot solve. I'll try to explain clearly.

First things first, so i'll briefly explain the logic. I have **Users** that can have several **Items**, so in each **user** i want to have an array of *objectId's* that identify the **items** they have.

I have User.js and userService.js files, as well as Item.js and itemService.js files.

My **User.js** file is as follows:

```
const restful = require('node-restful')
const mongoose = restful.mongoose
const validator = require('validator')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema


const utilizadorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, default: '', required: true, unique: true},
    email: { type: String, default: '', required: true, unique: true, validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Invalid email']},
    password: { type: String, default: '', required: true},
    equipaID: [{ 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Equipa'}],
    itens: [{ 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item'}],
    poderDeAtaque: { type: Number, default: 10},
    poderDeDefesa: { type: Number, default: 10},
    healthPoints: { type: Number, default: 100},
    classificacaoDuelos: { type: Number, default: 0},
    vitorias: { type: Number, default: 0},
    derrotas: { type: Number, default: 0},
    validado: { type: Boolean, default: false}
})

module.exports = restful.model('Utilizador', utilizadorSchema, 'Utilizadores')
```

Now, my **userService.js** file:

```
const Utilizador = require('./utilizador')
var item = require('./item')

Utilizador.methods(['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'])

Utilizador.update(
    {_id: Utilizador._id},
    { $push: {itens: item._id}},
    { upsert: true}
)

module.exports = Utilizador
```

**Item.js**:

```
const restful = require('node-restful')
const mongoose = restful.mongoose


const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    descricao: { type: String, required: true},
    categoria: { type: String, required: true},
    nivel: { type: Number, required: true},
    poderDeAtaque: { type: Number, required: true},
    poderDeDefesa: { type: Number, required: true},
    healthPoints: { type: Number, required: true},
})

module.exports = restful.model('Item', itemSchema, 'Itens')
```

**ItemService.js**:

```
const Item = require('./item')

Item.methods(['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'])

Item.updateOptions({new: true, runValidators: true})

module.exports = Item
```

So, my problem is this, i can successfully add an **item** to an **user**, however, when i try to add **another item** to the **same user**, it replaces the value in the array, instead of adding a new one. I've tried using **$addToSet** instead of **$push**, but to no success.

Comment: Don't you have a typo on `{ $push: {itens: item._id}}` did you mean `{ $push: {items: item._id}}`?

Comment: @Hammerbot I don't think so, in my **utilizadorSchema** i called it **itens**